# How can I fetch a whole string that include Chinese character with ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

For example, `1.txt`

```
a = "攻击力
非常高"

b = "防御力"
c = "防御力是#{example}"
d = "xyz"
```

I want the result:

```
"攻击力
非常高"

"防御力"

"防御力是#{example}"
```

And there is no `"xyz"` because it contains no Chinese character.

I tested  `/(\p{Han}+)/`, but it is not what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my example: [regex example](http://rubular.com/r/PBGBqJegXw)

Comment: Are only Chinese and ASCII symbols the options?

Comment: If the example is working on rubular why are you not using that regex

Comment: @Esailija Because I don't know how to select the whole sentence. Now it is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the regex as simple as possible:

```
# encoding: utf-8
a = "攻击力
非常高"

b = "防御力"
c = "防御力是example"
d = "xyz"

puts [a,b,c,d].select{|str| str =~ /\p{Han}/ }
# 攻击力
# 非常高
# 防御力
# 防御力是example

or, in case of one string:

# encoding: utf-8
a = "攻击力非常高
防御力
防御力是example
xyz"
puts a.lines.select{|line| line =~ /\p{Han}/ }.join
```

Comment: Hi, my situation is that all these variables are in a big string, and extract strings from this big string.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: `/([^[:ascii:]]+)/` a regex that selects all non-ascii symbols in the input. I tried it on your example and it really selects only the Chinese characters.

The regex you are searching for is probably:

```
/("[^"]*[^[:ascii:]]+[^"]*")/
```

If I got correctly what you need.

What I do:

- String should start with `"` `#"#[^"]*[^[:ascii:]]+[^"]*")`
- Then have any number of non `"` characters `"#[^"]*#[^[:ascii:]]+[^"]*")`
- Then at least one non-ascii symbol `"[^"]*#[^[:ascii:]]+#[^"]*")`
- Then have any number of non `"` characters `"[^"]*[^[:ascii:]]+#[^"]*#")`
- And should end with `"` `"[^"]*[^[:ascii:]]+[^"]*#"#)`

Comment: Thank you. Can I select the whole string? I mean if a string contains Chinese character, than it will be selected.

Comment: @goofansu I also added explanation of the regex I constructed

Comment: @goofansu: Note that a string that contains only Japanese hiragana/katakana, or contains Korean character can pass the test. You can make similar modification to your original regex to make it match only strings with real Chinese character.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you. I'll use `\p{Han}` to make a test.